# Change Resolution on OpenCV / Android

Tags: opencv, camera, resolution, android

I am using a Moto G II. It has resolutions on range (320 X 240 to 3264 X 2448). When a take a Picture normal it gets good like (1836 x 3264) but on my App using OpenCv its stops on @ 864 x 480. The code below only works if the values are less than 864 x 480.

```
mOpenCvCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(1920, 1080);
mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
```

I need capture good quality images.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the VideoCapture object settings by using the `set` method.

in C/C++:

```
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,3264);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,2448);
```

in Java:

```
cap.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 3264);
cap.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 2448);
```

Comment: Thanks. But we dont have in OpenCV4Androd this method.

Comment: On Android the OpenCv by default capture de Frame on Max value of display and not of the camera.

Comment: @RogeriodaSilva did you got the solution ?